# Drawerlayout not work after onbackpressed to previous activity

Tags: android

I have set DrawerLayout in the CustomFragmentActivity and it is just a super class for extends of my all activity. it is work.

but the problem is when i click the device back button to previous activity.

the DrawerLayout cannot call by button click in this moment but it can pull to open the DrawerLayout.

However, i just checked the onclick Listener and it is work but it cannot control the DrawerLayout open or close.

Please Help me to solve this problem. 
Thank you

Comment: You need to manually open/close drawer layout in your onBackPressed method or pass it's state back to the previous activity using startActivityForResult/onActivityResult pair and restore DrawerLayout's state on previous activity using received state.

Comment: @Lingviston 
Thank you for your guide and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually open/close `DrawerLayout` in your `onBackPressed` method or pass it's state back to the previous activity using `startActivityForResult`/`onActivityResult` methods pair and restore `DrawerLayout's` state on previous activity using received data.